# Вставить картинку в base64 из localStorage на html страницу

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Имею скрипт, который добавляет картинки в `localStorage` в таком виде.

[image]

Сами картинки отображаются на `html` странице, далее по клику я проверяю, был ли клик на картинку.
Если клик был проведен на картинку, она должна появиться в новом окне. Для этого мне нужно получить ее путь из `localStorage`, для чего пытаюсь использовать такой скрипт:

```
container.onclick = (e) => {
    var target = e.target; // элемент который вызвал событие
    if (target.tagName === "IMG"){
        console.log("img");
    } else {
        console.log("не картинка");
    }
    console.log(target);
};
```

Сам клик записывается в `target` и если его вывести к консоль, то получим объект такого типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше требуется получить путь к картинке, чтобы вставить ее в уже готовый блок на странице, и вот с этим и возникла проблема.

Comment: О каком пути речь? У Вас в base64 уже сама картинка

Comment: да, саму эту строку `source` можно присваивать атрибуту `src` картинки